# Condição (WHERE) com IF

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas (posts e posts_promovidos). Ambas se relacionam e a busca "normal" funciona sem problemas. Porém, preciso fazer uma busca que me retorne todos os posts e, caso o post pertença à posts_promovidos, me traga somente os posts_promovidos com status = "N".

Tentei algo do tipo

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS POST [...] WHERE [..] AND IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts_promovidos WHERE posts_promovidos.post_id = post.id) > 0,posts_promovidos.ativo = "N","")
```

Porém não funcionou como queria pois está trazendo apenas os posts promovidos e ignorando os posts "não promovidos" (que não constam da tabela posts_promovidos).

Qual seria a forma mais correta de fazer essa busca?

**EDIT - SOLUÇÃO**

Resolvi da seguinte maneira (compartilhando para ajudar quem tenha algo parecido):

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS POST [...] WHERE [..] AND posts.id NOT IN(select post_id from posts_promovidos) OR posts_promovidos.ativo = "N"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from posts_promovidos where posts_promovidos.status = "N"
inner join (select * from posts where posts.id not in posts_promovidos) p on p.id = posts_promovidos.id
```

Comment: Luis, bem vindo ao StackOverflow! Seria interessante se você juntasse ao código uma pequena explicação de como ele reponde à pergunta

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` resolve seu problema:

```
SELECT
   p.*
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_promovidos pp
    ON p.id = pp.id
    AND pp.status = 'N'
```

Comment: Já tenho o JOIN devidamente configurado e funcionando. Só tenho essa questão de, em alguns casos, verificar se o post está em posts_promovidos e, se estiver, que não esteja ativo (ativo = "N"). O JOIN é incondicional, ou seja, sempre vai acontecer.